# how to test paypal classic api in sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

paypal support two kinds of paypal apis:
first: new REST api (not completed, only support USD business)
second: classic api( support all currencies)

so i test the classic api in sandbox, but cant find anything about "account credentials" in the user's profile. who can help me???

config for skd_config.ini file:

```
;Account credentials
[Account]
acct1.UserName = xxxx@paypal.com
acct1.Password = xxxxx
acct1.Signature = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
acct1.AppId = APP-80W284485P519543T
```

Answer (score 0):

If your test sandbox seller account did not get these created by default, you can log into the account and manually create these.  In order to request an API credentials for your sandbox account, follow the steps below:

1.Log in to your test sandbox PayPal Premier or Business account.

2.Click the Profile subtab located in the top navigation area.

3.Click the Request API Credentials.
-Click  here if you see "API Access" instead of Step 3.

4.Click the "Set up PayPal API credentials and permissions" link.

5.Click the Request API Credentials link.
-Click  here if you see "View API Certificate" instead of Step 5

6.Click the Request API signature radio button and read the API Licence Agreement and Terms of Use.

7.Complete the API Credential Request form by clicking the Agree and Submit button.

8.Copy the values listed next to API Username and Password

9.Select the value listed next to Signature Hash, copy it, and save it to a file or some other location. This is your API Signature.